# Jquery Dialog, Adding a new line of styled text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I am trying to create a customer support dialog. I want the dialog to have two lines of text, and a title. The first line will be an error message, and the second will be a bold customer service number. This may be hard to picture so I added a dialog I made in paint to help out:
[image]

I tried making a new line statement (`string Error = "You have an error... number \n Customer Support...`) to see if I could separate the text but that did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why `\n`? You should use `<br />`.

```
"You have an error... number <br /> Customer Support: ..."
```